# Cannot resize root partition not even from live environment!

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I want to extend the root partition of my Ubuntu 20.04 machine and because I was dumb enough to not use LVM at install, I have to go into a live USB to do it.

My root is /dev/sdc1 as gparted shows [image: and has extra free space available]

There is unallocated space [image]

When I try to check it first, Gparted prints an error that I have to run resize2fs -f /dev/sdc1 first! [image: resize2fs -f /dev/sdc1]

But when I go into the terminal and use resize2fs -f /dev/sdc1 it goes into a loop with the check function! Check outputs normally and when i use resize2fs it says it needs check again. I run check again and then resize and it asks for check again. It's a never ending loop?

How can I make use of that free and unallocated space to grow /dev/sdc1?

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live USB/DVD and `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdc1` then `resize2fs -f /dev/sdc1`.

Comment: @crip659 No, first the user has to fix /dev/sdc1, and if they still wish to INCREASE /dev/sdc1 they can RESIZE /dev/sdc2, not delete it.

Comment: @heynnema if I understand correctly, that's what OP is doing: *"I have to go into a live USB to do it."* ... *" I run check"*.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity The user is not doing a `fsck`. That's the difference.

Comment: @heynnema rigth! sorry

Comment: @heynnema Thank you very much! Your original comment solved my problem! I feel ashamed it was that easy fix but in truth all I did is follow the onscreen instructions! sudo fsck -f was the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

Boot to a Ubuntu Live USB/DVD and `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdc1` then `resize2fs -f /dev/sdc1`.